# How to export data from salesforce to an ftp location?

Tags: integration

How to pick up and drop a file to an FTP location from salesforce

Comment: Welcome to the site anand, please note this question may well get closed unless you add more information. What do you want to export, what have you tried etc.

Answer (score 5):

There are many different things that you can do to get data out of Salesforce and FTP'd somewhere else.  There is no built in FTP functionality, though.

- You could use a 3rd party tool like [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/solutions/salesforce-integration) to configure a data export to a target FTP location (probably the easiest).
- You could script the [data loader](https://na15.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_data_loader.pdf) to extract the data and then schedule it using your OS (cron job, etc.) to run at your desired frequency and have file transfer management software (e.g., MOVEit) configured to pickup the files and move them to your desired location, or use something else to move the file(s).
- You could write a Java/C#/etc program to extract the data and FTP it.

The Jitterbit solution:
[image]